# Magento 2.4 create custom filter for products in listpage

Tags: magento2, collection, magento2.4, catalogsearch, elasticsearch

I'm migrating Magento 2.3 to 2.4.5. Already I have a working feature of a custom attribute filter in the Product list page also having a plugin but the class `Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\IndexBuilder` doesn't exist in Magento 2.4 for elastic search 7.

```
<type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\IndexBuilder">
        <plugin name="search_index_builder_restrict_product_after_get" type="Vendor\RestrictProduct\Plugin\CatalogSearch\Search\IndexBuilder" />
</type>
```

Also applied the same logic here for

```
<type name="Magento\Elasticsearch7\Model\Client\Elasticsearch">
        <plugin name="search_es_restrict_product_after_get" type="Vendor\RestrictProduct\Plugin\ElasticLayerPlugin" />
</type>
```

But the custom filter is not working.
My `Vendor\RestrictProduct\Plugin\ElasticLayerPlugin` is below

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\RestrictProduct\Plugin;

use Magento\Elasticsearch7\Model\Client\Elasticsearch;

class ElasticLayerPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $productCollectionFactory;


    protected $request;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function beforeQuery($subject,$query) {

        $customer = $this->customerSession->getCustomer();
        $customerGroupId = 0;
        if ($customer->getData()) {
            $customerGroupId = (int)$customer->getGroupId();
        }

        $filteredIds = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        if($customerGroupId>4) { 
            $filteredIds->addAttributeToFilter([
                                ['attribute' => 'customer_group', ['finset' => (int)$customerGroupId]],
                                ['attribute' => 'customer_group', ['finset' => 4]]]);

        } else {
            $filteredIds->addAttributeToFilter('customer_group', ['finset' => (int)$customerGroupId]);
        }

        if($this->request->getFullActionName()=='catalog_category_view') {      
            $filteredIds->addAttributeToFilter('sku', ['neq' => '6191']);
        }

        $filteredIds = $filteredIds->getAllIds();

        // This is where to fetch the entity_id array to filter the Elastic collection with
        //$filteredIds   = [3916];

        if(!$filteredIds || count($filteredIds) < 1)  {

            return [$query];
        }

        // Add the entity_id filter to the Elastic collection
        $query['body']['query']['bool']['filter'] = ['ids' => [ 'values' => $filteredIds]];


        return [$query];

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share few more details on what exactly you mean by "custom filter is not working" Also can you plz share the content of this file Vendor\RestrictProduct\Plugin\CatalogSearch\Search\IndexBuilder and the custom attribute configuration.

Comment: is your custom plugin calling when you go to listing page?

Comment: custom filter in the sense I have a custom attribute and I'll filter by value

Comment: Magento\Elasticsearch7\Model\Client\Elasticsearch
Yes this plugin is called in listpage. @RizwanKhan

Answer (score 3):

There is no issues with that plugin, as I tried the same plugin in a vanilla Magento and tried a custom filter, it is working as expected.

Plugin code:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Elasticsearch7\Model\Client\Elasticsearch">
        <plugin name="search_es_restrict_product_after_get" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\ElasticLayerPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> Vendor\Module\Plugin\ElasticLayerPlugin

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;

class ElasticLayerPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $productCollectionFactory;

    protected $request;

    /**
     * @param CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param Http $request
     */
    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        Http $request
    ) {
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function beforeQuery($subject, $query)
    {
        $filteredIds = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        /**
         * Configured 15, 19 activities in magento admin panel and tried to filter the results
         * 15 => Cycling
         * 19 => Overnight
         * */
        
        $filteredIds->addAttributeToFilter([
            ['attribute' => 'activity', ['finset' => 15]],
            ['attribute' => 'activity', ['finset' => 19]]]);

        if ($this->request->getFullActionName()=='catalog_category_view') {
            $filteredIds->addAttributeToFilter('sku', ['neq' => '6191']);
        }

        $filteredIds = $filteredIds->getAllIds();
        

        if (!$filteredIds || count($filteredIds) < 1) {
            return [$query];
        }
        
        $query['body']['query']['bool']['filter'] = ['ids' => [ 'values' => $filteredIds]];

        return [$query];
    }
}
```

Result:

**Before filter**
[image]

**After Filter**

[image]

I filtered the products by the "activity" attribute, and it is working as expected.

I hope there is some issue with your data, so that's why the custom filter is not working properly.

Possibilities for issues:

1. There is an issue with CustomerSession, it may not fetch the current customer  details, pls make sure the customer details by logging the data
2. Maybe any other third-party modules like Amasty override the native `Magento\Elasticsearch7\Model\Client\Elasticsearch` class, so pls make sure the plugins sort order
3. Log the `$filteredIds` before adding it into the filter, and check whether are you getting the expected result or not.

I hope it will help you!